# Facing duplicate column error while creating table

Tags: sql, hive

I am trying to create a table, however I am getting an error Duplicate column service type, here is my query:

```sql
create table online_data as

select * from customer_acct t1, customer_acct t2

where t1.service_type ='CC' and t2.service_type ='OB'

t1.key=t2.key

t1.time=t2.time
```

Comment: Do not use `*` when creating a table.... in this case you will have columns with the same name.

Comment: Since you are joining the same table to itself and doing a `SELECT *` every column in that table will be repeated. The new table can't use the same column name more than once as that would be nonsense. You will need to list out every column in each table and give the duplicated columns an alias for the new table. `SELECT t1.service_type as CC_service_type, t2.service_type as OB_service_type, t1.key as CC_key, t2.key as OB_key, t1.time as CC_Time, t2.time as OB_time <etc.> ` (as an example)

Comment: You should also learn ANSI SQL join syntax. The join syntax you’re using hasn’t been considered good practice for 30+ years

Comment: Please read [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). Note: It's a 13 year old article talking about old-style joins......

Comment: Can anyone tell me how can I convert this into window function